# Why be formed face to split when apply the Solidify modifier?

Tags: modifiers, faces, mirror

I'll make the modeling by two axis Mirror modifier. But, when, apply Solidify modifier, Its has be formed face split at meeting point vertex of the Mirror modifier.

Show you next pictures:
 - When apply the modifier not yet:

[image]

- When apply the modifier:

[image]

**Q. How to remove the faces?**

---

*blender_2.81*

Comment: Hello :). Just disable the *Mirror modifier* and delete the face in the middle.

Comment: @JachymMichal There isn't another ways for automation?

Comment: Hello :). Well, if you apply your *Mirror modifier* first, no inner face will be created.

Comment: @JachymMichal But, It's still do not remove the faces although apply the modifier.

Comment: Of course. You need to apply the *Mirror modifier* **before** the *Solidify modifier* :). That way, no inner faces are even created.

Comment: @JachymMichal Thank you I solved that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the "Clipping" option in the mirror modifier. If you don't, the two halves of the model are treated as if they're disconnected at the seam in the middle.

Comment: Hello :). Clipping only merges the center vertices, but the face stays - try it for yourself.

Comment: @JachymMichal Thank you for your answer. But, I wanna remove the faces with separated. Clipping is not removed the faces.